# How to communicate between two asp.net user control brothers?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I would like to know what is the best way to communicate between two asp.net user controls which are brothers.
The scenario is like this - there is a father contorl, called Main.Aspx,
and inside there are two instances of child controls, called - "Left.aspx" and "Right.aspx"

I would like to send a string from left.aspx to right.aspx, so right.aspx will do some server work on it. As much as I know, javascript functions on both controls are visible to each other, so perhaps JS is the better way to communicate (but in that case controls would be less generic)? Or is it better to use some sort of this.Parent.FindControl("Right") on server side?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Maybe this can be of aid (similar to your situation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735670/how-to-communicate-between-asp-net-custom-controls